# How to turn off Twitter's Suggestions for you / Who(m) to follow?

Tags: twitter

I am looking for a method/option to remove the new Twitter's suggestions feature.

Assuming it works in a similar fashion to Facebook ... if I keep hiding users ... will it eventually go away ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, a custom CSS for twitter.com to hide `<div id="recommended_users">` should work.

*Updated*: Or just use this script: http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/83086